# RPM package signature verification in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, rpm

I am verifying the RPM package signature of a package on an Ubuntu machine with command `rpm -Kv <package name>`, and this command is not reporting any errors. Whereas the same command on a Fedora machine is detecting issues with the RSA header, which is expected because the package is malformed.

This is the result on the Fedora machine:

[image: RPM logs]

Is there any way to verify the malformed RPM package in Ubuntu?

Comment: Stack Overflow is for _programming_ questions. You might want to explore our sibling site [unix.se], but please read their help pages before asking there (and please delete this off-topic post, and review our [help] before posting here again).